# How to hide text without ID?

Tags: css

I’m writing a css style for a web page that displays text without id, inside a div. Here’s the bit i’m interested in:

```html
<div class="wal2">

    <meta content="***" itemprop="width"></meta>
    <meta content="***" itemprop="height"></meta>

     text1: 

    <a target="_blank" href="**********"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <br></br>

    text2: 

    <a target="_blank" href="***************"></a>
    <br></br>
    <table></table>
    <a href="/crop.php?id=303213"></a>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <img width="16" height="16" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="" src="/files/color.gif"></img>

    text3:

    <br></br>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"></table>

</div>
```

I want to know how do i hide ‘ *text3:*’ **without** hiding ‘*text1*: and *text2:*' with css, using 
***{ text-indent: 100%;   white-space: nowrap;   overflow: hidden;  }***
or ***{ display: none !Important; }***, or whatever else.. ?
And if that is not possible, how can i hide all three of them ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're unable to change the HTML?

Comment: Yes. I need to do it through a css style.

Comment: why cant you add classes to text1/2/3 ? or id ?  basically its possible in case the tags always remain the same you could do it by getting `wal2` child nodes and then seperate the data by tags but that much more work then just add a parent div to each one of them

Comment: Do you mean the actual words 'text3:'?  Or the block of html following it?  If the layout is consistent, you can target the table with something like `table:nth-of-type(2) { display:none;}`.

Comment: Yes, i need to block the actual text, so nth-of-type(*) doesn’t work. The text is not selectable through ‘element inspector’ or ‘dom inspector’.
@Gal.  I’m afraid i don’t know how to achieve that, so i can’t test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide all text nodes (not the preferred solution, but requested nonetheless); you could try to collapse the visibility on the parent div and then restore it on the html elements:

```css
.wal2 {
  visibility: collapse;
}
a,
br,
table,
img {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wal2">

  <meta content="***" itemprop="width"></meta>
  <meta content="***" itemprop="height"></meta>

  text1:

  <a target="_blank" href="**********">link</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">alert('script');</script>
  <br></br>

  text2:

  <a target="_blank" href="***************">link</a>
  <br></br>
  <table></table>
  <a href="/crop.php?id=303213">link</a>
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <img width="16" height="16" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"></img>

  text3:

  <br></br>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>table cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: That did work as a secondary solution.
I still want to hide the desired text (if possible), but until then, your solution will do. Thank You.